# How can i validate a String which includes an Expression/Condition

Tags: javascript, regex, string

*Hello Community!*

I am looking for a way to validate an expression, like a condition in an IF block, that is stored in a string.

Example:

```
expression = "2 + 3 == 5"; //or "true || false == true"

if(validationFunc(expression)){
   //do something
}

...

//validates the string and returns a boolean-value
function validationFunc(str) {
   //do validation
   var regex = /^([\s()!]*(([0-9]+)|(true|false){1})[\s()]*[+\-=\*%!]*)+$/g;

   return str.match(regex);
}
```

There is the possiblity to validate the 'Expression-String' with **Regex**. I tried to make a Regex-Expression, but it seems to be more complex than i expected. In addition, I found no solution to this problem in the web.

Has somebody a solution for this problem, or is there a other way to match/validate such a string?

Valid inputs:

```
true
1 == true
203 == true
0 == false
true == true
true != false
(true && false) || true == true
true == (true && false) || true
20 + 40 == 60
...
```

Invalid inputs:

```
empty string
true 0
'' != 20
30 && 4 == true
20 + 3 == false
...
```

Comment: `eval`? .......?

Comment: Do you want to validate if this is a valid *expression* or if the result is *correct*?

Comment: Can you please give valid and invalid inputs

Comment: i want to validate if its an expression or not

Comment: do you need just *some* expression or one with a given style?

Comment: Why is `203 == true` valid but `' ' != 20` is invalid? They are both valid equality checks, what makes one not like the other?

Comment: @NinaScholz the user can set any expression and i need to validate this string. If it is an expression or not.

Comment: @VLAZ sorry my fault!! i mean when there is an empty string with '!= 20'

Comment: @Brunhack I still don't know why one would be valid, the other invalid. From what I can gather all the valid inputs evaluate to `true` but invalid ones evaluate to `false`. Is that what you're trying to validate?

Comment: @NinaScholz only the eval function is not enough i think :/ because it generates an ERROR by invalid inputs ...

Comment: if the user can input a string, then i would use `eval` with a `try ... catch` statement. otherwise you need a decent parser for it.

Comment: Still unclear for me. Why `30 && 4 == true` and `20 + 3 == false` are invalids? The syntax is correct and they returns both `false`.

Comment: @VLAZ exaclty!  that is what i need...

Comment: @NinaScholz that seems to be a solution! thank you! i will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`try ... catch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) and use the exception for an addtional return.

If wanted, you could return `true` (yes, it's an expression), instead of the evaluated value.

```js
function check(expression) {
    var result;
    try {
        result = eval(expression);
    } catch (error) {
        return error.toString();
    }
    return result;
}

var expressions = ['30 && 4 == true', '20 + 3 == false', 'f*ck'];

console.log(expressions.map(check));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function isValid(expr) {
  try {
    return eval(expr);
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}

// Valid ; Correct syntax and return true
console.log(isValid(`true`));
console.log(isValid(`true == (true && false) || true`));

// Not valid
console.log(isValid(`true 0`)); // Incorrect syntax
console.log(isValid(`true === 0`)); // Correct syntax but returns false
```

Comment: You'll also have to capture the return value of `eval` - OP only wants expressions that evaluate to `true` to be valid.

Comment: I saw his last comment after posting this... Updated.

Comment: Thank You for your help! ;)